# How do I search for a Word in a class thats build out of a another class?

Tags: java, arrays, string

Good evening!

I have been trying to get things done for the whole day and I have definitly reached my limit. I have created a class "entry" that consists of a name (String), an adress (String) and a tel number (int).
Furthermore, I have created a class called "phoneDirectory" and it consists of an array from the class entry.

My goal is it right now to create a method that searches that array for a name given and outputs the whole entry.

Things I have tried so far:

```
public void searchEntry(String name) {

   for(int i = 0; i < directory.length; i++) { 
    if(directory[i] != null) {
        System.out.println(directory[i].contains(name));
        }else {
            System.out.println("no entry");
        }
    }
  }
 }
```

---

```
 public void searchEntry(String name) {

 for(int i = 0; i < directory.length; i++) { 
    if(directory[i] != null) {
        if(Arrays.asList(directory[i]).contains(name)); //It says: "Unlikely argument type String for contains(Object) on a Collection <entry>"
        }else {
            System.out.println("no entry");
        }
       }
     }
   }
```

---

```
 public void searchEntry(String name) {

 for(int i = 0; i < directory.length; i++) { 
    if(directory[i] != null) {
        if(directory[i].contains(name)){ //The method contains(String) is undefinded for the type entry
        }else {
            System.out.println("no entry");
        }
    }
}
}
```

---

And many others by searching with google but nothing worked or gave me a "no entry" even though there is an entry with the String.
I would really appreciate it if someone could help me with this one. Thanks a lot.

The code for the 2 classes:

```
public class Entry{

private String name;
private String adress;
private int number;

public Entry(String name, String adress, int number) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.adress = adress;
    this.number= number;
}

    @Override
public String toString() {
    return  "\n" + name + ": " + adress + " , " + number+ "\n";
}




public class PhoneDirectory{

 private Entry[] directory;

public PhoneDirectory(Entry[] directory) {
    super();
    this.directory= directory;
}
```

Comment: Can you share code for your two classes also?

Comment: I have added it to the post. Thank you for taking your time.

Comment: You are just missing to call `name` on your entry: `dictionary[i].name.contains(name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the question `PhoneDirectory` class has a `Entry` type array named `directory` and you have implemented the `searchEntry` method.

You can implement `searchEntry` as shown below:

```
public void searchEntry(String name) {

   for(int i = 0; i < directory.length; i++) { 
    if(directory[i] != null) {

       if(directory[i].getName().equals(name)){
         System.out.println(directory[i]); 
         break; // assuming name is unique so you don't need to continue looping once name is found
       }
    }else {
            System.out.println("no entry");
    }
   }
 }
```

Also you need to implement `getters` inside your Entry class as all attributes are private, so that you can access them inside `Directory` class.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you!! Cant believe I didnt think about that all day.

Comment: please override to string

Comment: @李振纲 thanks for pointing it out. I have edited the answer. As `directory[]` contains `Entry` and that already has overridden `toString()`

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `.contains()` on the `Entry` instead of the `name` String.

You can just use Java Streams to search for results:

```
public void searchEntry(String name) {
    Arrays.stream(directory)
            .filter(e -> e.name.contains(name))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Or if you want to print a message if no entry is found you can use this:

```
public void searchEntry(String name) {
    List<Entry> matches = Arrays.stream(directory)
            .filter(e -> e.name.contains(name))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    if (matches.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("no entry");
    } else {
        matches.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the unformatted message.
If 'directory' type is Array of entry, then you can't find there String (which is 'name')

`if(Arrays.asList(directory[i]).contains(name));`

You have to compare name which you want to find and name from entry. For example:
You have those classes:

```
   public class Entry {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}


 public class PhoneDirectory {
    private Entry[] entries;

    public Entry searchEntry(String name) {
        for (Entry entry : entries) {
            if (entry.getName().equals(name)) {
                return entry;
            }
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("There is no entry with name: "+name);
    }
}
```

After that, I would advise if you don't know how many entries contain phoneDirectory then use List instead of Array.
One more thing, if you search for something, a user (and you) expect this 'something' as a result.